# Rewrite_Mod models and views to sub-domain using htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

Ok so I kind of understand that htaccess uses regular expressions and a series of conditions and rules, but am having trouble writing something that will work for what i'm looking for.

I have two domains in the same parent folder and want to be able to use some of the models and views from domain.com on sub-domain.com with codeinighter being used on both. Lately i've been creating a view in the sub-domain's directory and then using a "require_once" tag to import the models and views". However, as the project goes on, I find it very annoying to have to create each file separately.

Is there a way I can use htaccess to make it so codeignighter on the sub-domain knows to look in /domain.com/application/models/ and /domain.com/application/views/ if one cannot be found in the sub-domain, while also keeping the /index.php/test --> /test mapping in place.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

- parent (not actual directory name, not sure if this even matters)

  - domain.com

    - application

      - models
      - views
  - api.domain.com

    - application

      - models
      - views

This .htaccess is getting too complicated for me to understand and any help on this topic is helpful. I'm not even sure if htaccess can tell php to do this or if it's even possible. Perhaps that's the problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with htaccess your options are pretty limited. yes you can define some routing, and yes you could try defining variables in your htaccess that you can later access with php, but that wouldn't allow you to access `models` or `views` in the manner you want e.g. looking in 2 paths for one file.

to do that, you would have to modify the way codeigniter loads `models` and `views`. if you take a look under the hood in `system/core/Loader.php` you'll see a bunch of variables at the top. some of which, contain constants that are defined in `index.php` which indicate paths:

`protected $_ci_model_paths = array(APPPATH);`

you would either have to "hack" this file, or [extend it](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class) and modify the corresponding variables to contain `array('path1', 'path2')` so CI would know where to look.

with regards to routing, I'm not sure how you plan on handling that, but it could get messy.

you might want to look in to an [hmvc approach](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src). maybe you don't want to use hmvc, but the way they modify loading paths would be useful to you.